# BackboneJS + Codeigniter pushState true not working

Tags: codeigniter, backbone.js, backbone-routing

So I have this Backbone App where I use Codeigniter for the Backend. For some reason, `pushState:true` does not work.

So, my main.js of my backbone app has this:

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: App.ROOT });
```

My app.js has this:

```
var App = {
    ROOT: '/projects/mdk/'
};
```

and my navigation module, which renders the menulinks, each item has this:

```
this.insertView(new ItemView({
model: new Navigation.ItemModel({
    href: App.ROOT + 'home',
    class: 'home',
    triggers: 'home',
    route: this.route
   })
}));
```

and the model for it:

```
Navigation.ItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        href: '',
        text: '',
        triggers: [],
        route: ''
    }
});
```

All I get from this is "Page not found"...

**Add**: When I in the view change it to `href:'#news'` - it works, but it dont really makes sense...

Anyone who knows the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (http://backbonejs.org/#History):

> Note that using real URLs requires your web server to be able to
>   correctly render those pages, so back-end changes are required as
>   well. For example, if you have a route of /documents/100, your web
>   server must be able to serve that page, if the browser visits that URL
>   directly.

The problem is that your server isn't responding to whatever URL your app is on. For **every** URL that your Backbone app can reach, your server **MUST** return a valid HTML page (contianing your Backbone app).

Comment: Hmm yeah... what I just discovered is that if I enter `http://localhost/project/mdk/#news` - the page loads and the URL says `http://localhost/project/mdk/news` - shows everything the proper way!? Wtf?

Comment: That's because your server is responding to http://localhost/project/mdk, then Backbone is handling the "news" component and updating the URL. Once again, your problem is that your server isn't responding with a Backbone application when you access http://localhost/project/mdk/news

Answer (score 0):

ok I found a solution by myself:

I made this hack:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a:not([data-bypass])', function (evt) {

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if (href && href.indexOf('#') === 0) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);
        }
    });
```

and then I made:

```
href: '#home',
```

That solved the problem, now evereythings runs fluently..