# Backbone.js And Push State

Tags: backbone.js, pushstate

I'm using Backbone.js to develop a Web App and I have a doubt with the correct use of routing and Html5 Push State. Here my code

```
var HoopRouter  = new HoopApp.Router.RequestManager;
Backbone.history = Backbone.history || new Backbone.History({});
Backbone.history.start({
    root      : '/web_app',
    pushState : true
});
```

And in a method I'm doing this :

```
Backbone.history.navigate('#gameScreen/31', { trigger : true });
```

This workds correctly but giving me a url like this `https://my_host/web_app/gameScreen/31` but when I enter this url in the navigation bar and press enter the browser says that the url is not found in this server and also the href links are not working. If I check the pushState to false, it works well but Backbone use the "#" routes and I want to use the "/" routes.
I'm don't know if I'm forgetting something.

Comment: Do you actually have a page corresponding to https://my_host/web_app/gameScreen/31 or a server-side router that would serve up this page? Based on what you've showed us so far, I see no defined client-side routes, so unless the answer to the previous question is yes, I wouldn't expect this to work.

Comment: At the moment this are my defined client-side routes {
   ""                  : "index",
   "gameScreen/:gameid" : "html5game",
   ":whatever"         : "notFound"
  }

Comment: Your server will want to try to serve this route as well, so you'll need to have it explicitly ignore the route if you want client-side routing only. One typical way to handle this is to have it handle the base route and cut off anything after that in the url so it treats all routes from that base url as the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server needs to return a value for **every** URL your client can generate when using pushState. See [BackboneJS + Codeigniter pushState true not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779544/backbonejs-codeigniter-pushstate-true-not-working/21779639#21779639)